# statistic for defining which of two distributions a point comes from?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, threshold

I have 2 samples from what I can assume are 2 different distributions, $X$ and $Y$ (I don't know anything about the true distributions, but have the empirical distributions of the samples).
How can I define a threshold *t* such that I could say with confidence $\alpha$ that any new datapoint with value above/below *t* came from distribution $X$ ?

Comment: For example, you can compare the density estimation of the new point using two Kernel Density estimators (trained on the two samples)

Comment: @ItamarMushkin - given that the densities of the new point according to the two samples are $x$ and $y$, what value of $x/y$ (or $|x-y|$ ?) should I use to say that the point belongs to $X$ with p-value $< 1-\alpha$ ? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure. Personally, I'd take the Bayesian route here: If the new point have to come from either $X$ or $Y$ (is this your case?), and you have no prior preference to either, then the probability to belong to $X$ is just $x/(x+y)$.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin thanks again!  
Yes, the new point will come from either $X$ or $Y$. In general I am trying to define regions where any new point can confidently be said to belong to $X$ with confidence level $\alpha$.  
So this should be any region with $x/(x+y) > \alpha$? Do you know if that can equivalently be expressed as 'the point belongs to $X$ with p-value $1-\alpha$'?  
Re the prior - one of the populations is much large than the other. Does this mean I would multiply by $|Y|/|X|$?

Comment: Talking about probability, when you can, is more direct than talking about p-values; In your case, since each new point can belong only to one of the two distributions, I wouldn't formulate your problem as a hypothesis testing. But than again, I'm not that fluent in Frequentist, maybe someone else will have a better answer for you.

Comment: About the prior - think carefully if the size of the sample should be part of your prior or if it is encapsulated in the density estimation (more points = higher likelihood, generally speaking). But check it carefully for your problem.